# How to use scrollbar widget function in another Tkinter class and bind it to buttons

Tags: python, button, tkinter, scrollbar, tk-toolkit

I've created a Tkinter class, Ext() with a scrollbar for any text in the variabel self.text in the create_scrollbar() method. I want to use this method by binding it to Buttons in the class Application so that when the Button is pressed the text shows up in a scrollbar. I've tried to implement this as one class first but it lead to issues when using two **init** in the same class. How do I invoke create_scrollbar in Ext in the callback, self.callback in the Applications class ?

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
class Ext(tk.Frame):

    """ a scrollbar creation class, extends the class Application"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ init the frame """
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)

        self.text = tk.StringVar()



        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.scrollbar = tk.Canvas(master, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.scrollbar, background="#ffffff")
        self.txt = tk.Scrollbar(master, orient="vertical", command=self.scrollbar.yview)
        self.scrollbar.configure(yscrollcommand=self.txt.set)
        self.scrollbar.configure(width=500, height=200)

        self.txt.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.scrollbar.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                                  tags="self.frame")



        self.create_scrollbar()

    def create_scrollbar(self):

        tk.Label(self.frame, text=self.text).grid(column=1)








class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        """ init the frame """
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):


        Button = Button(self, text = "Display scrollbar!", command = self.callback)
        Button.grid(row = 10, column = 1, sticky = W)




    def callback(self):
        self.text = "this is a test sentence

        print create_scrollbar(t)  # Print scrollbarwidget from the Ext() class when the Button is pressed
#Main
root = Tk()
root.title("Maltparser1.0_demo")

root.geometry("900x700")
root.mainloop()


app = Application(root)
master = tk.Tk()

master  = Ext(master)
master.title("Instructions")
master.geometry("800x300")
Ext(master).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: "the text shows up in a scrollbar" makes no sense. Text can't be "in" a scrollbar. Do you mean "with"? Or, when you say "in a scrollbar" you really mean that you want a label widget where the text slowly scrolls ? Your `create_scrollbar` function doesn't create a scrollbar, so it's a little confusing.

Comment: Pardon,exactly, meant with.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, to call the `create_scrollbar` method you first need to create an instance of the class. For example:

```
def callback:
    e = Ext(self)
    e.create_scrollbar()
```

However, this won't do what you think it will, because you never tell it what text to display. In `callback`, `self.text` lives in the `App` class, not the `Ext` class. Perhaps you want to pass the string or a textvariable to the constructor of the `Ext` class.

As an aside, you code is *very* confusing. You create a frame named `self.frame` -- which makes sense --  but a canvas named `self.scrollbar`, a scrollbar named `self.txt`, and a stringvar named `self.text`. You then have a method called `create_scrollbar` which creates a label. And finally, you create a button from the class `Button`, and then name it `Button`. You can't have both a class and an instance with the same exact name.

Maybe those names make sense to you, but as someone who is not you, I think your name choices make your code extremely hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks, I've renamed the variables, I agree with you about  the previous names. The callback works and I'm trying to create Toplevel so that the clicks opens popups, I've tried replacing   Frame.__init__(self, master) with tkinter.Toplevel.__init__(self, master) but it doesn't work.